# Google Map Clustering not working with single location

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am using [Google Map Clustering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering) and opening [Info Windows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple) after clicking on particular cluster using `clusterclick` which is working absolutely fine.

However, when  I have single location, its not going inside `clusterclick` event and hence I am unable to open my Info Window.

I am trying to add below events but its not firing when I have single location as data.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'click', (function (markers) {
                         alert('markersclick');

                    })(markers));

                     google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function () {
                        alert('mapclick');
                    });
```

Here is my full source code (I have not added Info Window code because as of not even above events not firing).

```
<div id="map"></div>

<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY"> 
</script>



<script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<script>
    function initMap() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {lat: -28.024, lng: 140.887}
  });

  // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
  var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';


  var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      label: labels[i % labels.length]
    });
  });

                google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'click', (function (markers) {
                         alert('markersclick');

                    })(markers));

                     google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function () {
                        alert('mapclick');
                    });

  // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
      {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m',
       gridSize: 100,
  zoomOnClick: true,
  maxZoom: 10});

  google.maps.clusterclick.addListener(markerCluster, "clusterclick", function(cluster, event) {
      alert('hey');
  });
}
var locations = [
  {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
  {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
   {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
   {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
  {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
   {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
    {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
  {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
   {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
   {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
  {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
   {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
   {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
  {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
   {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
   {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
  {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
   {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
    {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
  {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
   {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
   {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
  {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
   {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312}
];

initMap();
</script>

<style>
    #map {
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

If I change my `locations` array to something like this.

```
var locations = [
  {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312}, 
];
```

Then my `clusterclick` not firing as well as `markers` click event.

Also I am getting an error saying..

> TypeError: google.maps.clusterclick is undefined

But I can have records like this.

Can someone guide me what I am doing wrong here ? Why its not working with single location ?

Comment: `markers` is an array of `google.maps.Marker` objects. You can't add the listener on the array. You have to loop your array and add the listener to each `Marker` individually. Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/4k4d5vtL/) except that here the markers are created within the loop but I suppose you get the idea.

Comment: There is a javascript error with the posted code: `(index):94 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addListener' of undefined` (this line: `google.maps.clusterclick.addListener(markerCluster, "clusterclick", function(cluster, event) {`, that isn't valid)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array.prototype.map() method add infowindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39838899/array-prototype-map-method-add-infowindow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you posted, `markers` is an array of `google.maps.Marker` objects. You can't add the listener on the array. You have to loop through your array and add the listener to each `Marker` individually.

```js
function initMap() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {
      lat: -28.024,
      lng: 140.887
    }
  });

  // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
  var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

  var locations = [{
      lat: -31.563510,
      lng: 147.154312
    },
    {
      lat: -31.563610,
      lng: 147.154312
    },
    {
      lat: -31.563710,
      lng: 147.154312
    },
    {
      lat: -31.563810,
      lng: 147.154312
    }
  ];

  var markers = [];

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: locations[i],
      map: map,
      label: labels[i % labels.length]
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent('Label: ' + this.getLabel());
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });

    markers.push(marker);
  }

  // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m',
    gridSize: 100,
    zoomOnClick: true,
    maxZoom: 10
  });
}


initMap();
```

```css
#map {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
```